# How to predict a prayer direction in the east relative to Jerusalem?

Tags: tefilla, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Is it possible to say that in a location that has sunset before Jerusalem, in this location the sunset is the direction of the prayer?

In other words, if we are in a place that is East of Jerusalem, we can follow the sunset. I'd like to know if it is correct.

Comment: This only works in locations directly east of Jerusalem but not e.g., in the South or South East of Jerusalem. Easiest is to look at the map, see where Jerusalem is and find the right direction on a compass (incl. on most smartphones)

Comment: @Deuteronomy, no. My question now is exactly the opposite and refers to something we didn't deal with.